# Two elements in foreach function separated with end "&&" symbols

Tags: javascript

I know that I can use `[element,element].forEach` but can i use `&&` symbols like in my code

I am asking is javascript syntax like this valid? correct?

I am asking because code is working fine but i can't find answer on my question

```
currencyIcon[i] && prices[i].addEventListener('click',function(){ 

     console.log("works");

});
```

Comment: Do you mean that your code is equal to this  https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRPmp.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not going to work.

the AND sign (`&&`) is executing the code in the left, and if it return true - it is executing the code in the right. so the left is seperated from the right code.

Comment: you are right man the code is not woking :d

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking is `x && y()` valid, the answer is yes.

Depending on complexity you might want `if (x) { y() }` but the code is effectively the same.

The `x && y()` shorthand is often used as a quick form of the same thing. Some people are used to programming languages where `y() if x` is possible, so the closest thing in JavaScript uses `&&` instead.

If you want something where you can run the same operation on multiple objects then what you need is different:

```js
[ currencyIcon[i], prices[i] ].forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', () => { 
    console.log("works");
  });
});
```

Note using the [arrow-function style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) here for brevity.

This iterates over each element of the array, here termed `e`, and runs the same code on it.

Comment: I think by that code OP thinks that it will work like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRPmp.png

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal That's a very good point. Added more code along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

`[element_1,element_2].forEach` is **not** equivalent to `element_1 && element_2.forEach`

The first one loops through an array and takes a callback function for each element,

The second one executes the first code on the left and if it returns `true` or anything other than `false`, `0`, `null` ...etc, it continues to the next one.

```js
const x = () => false;
const y = () => true;
const z = () => console.log('this is y');

x() && z(); // will not call z() because x() returns false
y() && z(); // will call z() because y() returns true
```